# Attaching a file to a page without adding to media library?

Tags: pages, media, media-library

We are using WP for our new intranet, which will primarily be used for documentation and archiving. We have some pages where we want to attach PDFs, documents, images, etc. However, we do *not* want these media items to be added to the media library when we attach them to a page; i.e., if the page is deleted, the media items are also deleted. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Media items shouldn't be deleted when a post or a page is deleted.

If you're hosting them somewhere else you can just paste the URL/path the file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a solution out of the box, and any files uploaded to WP are publically available to anyone who can access the domain, so you might want to keep that in mind.

You'll need to code a solution, possibly as follows:

- on post creation, use `wp_insert_post` to create the require folder.
- Use something like `glob($root_folder.$post_slug . "/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,pdf}",GLOB_BRACE)` to list all files in the post-specific folder . (Note, if the slug is ever changed, you'll need to manually rename the folder or automate it somehow.
- Use `before_delete_post` to delete the folder & all files.